# Traer los nombre de una tercera tabla, tablas relacionadas Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas noches no consigo llevarme bien con las relaciones en Laravel y mira que creo entender el concepto pero muchas veces no consigo sacar lo que quiero.

**Mi tabla clientes**

| id | name | foto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nombre1 | foto.jpg |
| 1 | nombre2 | foto.jpg |

**Mi tabla de ubicaciones**

| id | cliente_id | direccion | ciudad | poblacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | C/prueba | 46 | 7219 |
| 1 | 53 | Av del puerto | 46 | 7219 |

**Mi tabla provincias**

| id | provincia |
| --- | --- |
| 46 | Valencia |

**Mi tabla municipios**

| id | municipio |
| --- | --- |
| 7219 | Paterna |
| 1689 | Torrent |

En mi tabla ubicaciones `ciudad` es la que va con la `id` de la tabla `provincias`
También en ubicaciones `poblacion` es la que va con la `id` de la tabla `municipios``

Entonces mi query la realizo de la siguiente manera.

```
$clientes = Cliente::with('ubicaciones')->leftjoin('etiquetas', 'clientes.etiqueta_id', '=', 'etiquetas.id')->select('clientes.*', 'etiquetas.name AS nameEti')->whereIn('tipo_cliente', [1,3])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Mi iteración en la vista de clientes:

```
@foreach ($clientes as $clie)  
    {{ $clie->ubicaciones['poblacion'] }} ({{ $clie->ubicaciones['ciudad'] }})
    //Aquí consigo sacar las ids de la poblacion y ciudad
@endforeach
```

Mi modelo Cliente:

```
public function ubicaciones()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Ubicacion::class, 'cliente_id');
}
```

Mi modelo ubicaciones:

```
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Cliente', 'id');
}

public function Provincia(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Provincia::class, 'provincia');

}
```

Entonces lo que quiero sacar es el nombre de la provincia y el del municipio, pero no hay forma.

Comentar que tanto la tabla de provincias como la de municipios está en otra conexión diferente, pero no creo que eso sea un problema teniendo creado el modelo, no?

Comment: Si muchas gracias @BetaM como siempre ;)

Comment: Sugiero removamos todos los comentarios hechos así no distraemos con dudas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final después de mucho probar el fallo estaba en el modelo de Ubicación, donde no le estaba dando bien los campos a comprobar.

```
>belongsTo(Provincia::class, 'ciudad', 'id');
```

Comprobamos el campo `ciudad` de la tabla Ubicacion con `id` de la tabla Provincias y por fin sale el nombre.